# Are all central simple algebras unital?

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras, brauer-group

The definition I'm using for a CSA over a field $k$ is the following:

A CSA over $k$ is a finite-dimensional associative $k$-algebra which is simple and has center precisely $k$.

My question concerns whether implicitly, every CSA is unital. If $A$ is a unital $k$-algebra, then there is a natural way to embed $k$ into the center of $A$ via $k \mapsto k \cdot 1_A$, but can it be done without a unit element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, central simple algebras are unital, since as you observe there is no obvious way to embed $k$ into $A$ when $A$ is merely a non-unital $k$-algebra.

Indeed, there might not even be any such embedding at all. Consider the smallest non-unital subring of $\mathbb{R}$ containing all rational multiples of $\pi$ (say), viewed as a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra in the obvious way. This has no nonzero idempotent elements, so there is no embedding of $\mathbb{Q}$ into it.

Comment: Is your subring not describing the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $x = \pi$?

Comment: @CharalambosKioulos No - it doesn't actually contain any nonzero rationals as elements (and that's crucial). Concretely, it's the set of all numbers of the form $$\sum_{i=1}^nq_i\pi^{a_i}$$ with each $a_i$ a **positive** (in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, we just require nonnegativity) integer and each $q_i$ a rational (together with $0$). (The fact that this is in fact disjoint from $\mathbb{Q}_{\not=0}$ is just the transcendentality of $\pi$.)

Comment: Oops, I see thanks!